# Customer Convertor for java.util.list to array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a List of an object type say Customer class (attribute: customerId, customerName) and an array of String.

Is there any way to populate/get an array with all customerName from list? (except to manually iterate over the list)
i.e.

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(1,"ABC");
Customer c2 = new Customer(2,"DEF");
Customer c3 = new Customer(3,"XYZ");
List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
list.put(c1); list.put(c2); list.put(c3);

String[] allCustomerNames = new String[list.size()];
//Code to get allCustomerNames populated.
//Ofcourse, other than to iterate through list
```

Is there any way which would be similar to...

```
allCustomerNames = list.toArray(customerNameConvertor);
```

where customerNameConveror is hypothetical convertor class which would tell to use customerName for population of array elements.

Comment: You can use [JOSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net) to query on your List.

Comment: There is no way to get name without iterate but you can add your names to another list simultaneously then convert it to array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a third-party library such as [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [F4J](http://www.f4j.rethab.ch/).

This is how it can look like in Guava:

```
Function<Customer, String> customerToName = new Function<Customer, String>() {
        public String apply(Customer c) {
            return c.getName();
       };

List<String> allCustomerNamesList = Lists.transform(list, customerToName);
```

If you need an array, you'll have to use the normal toArray method: `allCustomerNames = allCustomerNamesList.toArray(allCustomerNames);`

Comment: +1, A small note that this still internally iterates through the list - however, the iteration bit is done in the library and the client just needs to be aware of the functional bit which is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an utility class like this. You can get array of value for all fields.

```
public class FieldToArrayConvertor {
    public static Object[] getFieldValuesFromEntityList(List list, String fieldName) throws Exception {
        Object[] array = new Object[list.size()];
        int i=0;
        for(Object o : list) {
            Class<? extends Object> aClass = o.getClass();
            Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            Object invoke = field.get(o);
            array[i]= invoke;
            i++;
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            Employee em = new Employee("emp1");
            Employee em1 = new Employee("emp2");
            List<Employee> list1= new ArrayList() ;
            list1.add(em);
            list1.add(em1);
            Object[] field = getFieldValuesFromEntityList(list1, "name");
            for(Object o: field) {
                System.out.println(o);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FieldToArrayConvertor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**See Also:** [Uses of Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)